# Starting Wait for Plymouth Boot Screen to Quit

Tags: ubuntu, nvidia, kubuntu

I'm struggling to install Kubuntu 15.04 on my PC. I've got a GTX 970 which i think is throwing off the trial mode from starting up. nomodeset doesn't work, so I tried nouveau.noaccel=1 to beget this error screen. At this point I don't fully understand how to proceed, so any help would be great.

[image]

Comment: Also I am very sorry about IQ but I literally don't have a better camera.

Comment: I have the same error when I'm trying to install Ubuntu 15.04

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when trying to install Centos 7. For me the hang disappeared when adding `single` to the grub command line (e.g. pressing 'e' to edit while the boot menu is present).